# mongoengine.errors.ValidationError: Integer value is too small

Tags: mongodb, flask, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I have a simple User schema in mongoDB for my Flask server. I am using mongoengine to work with the database. The schema is as follows:

```
class User(Document):
    username = StringField(unique=True, requireed=True)
    email = EmailField(unique=True)
    password = StringField(required=True)
    creditCount = IntField(default=0, min_value=0, max_value=None)
    date_created = DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow)

    def json(self):
        user_dict = {
            "username": self.username,
            "email": self.email,
            "creditCount": self.creditCount,
        }

        return json.dumps(user_dict)

    meta = {
        "indexes": ["username"],  # index based on username
        "ordering": ["-date_created"],  # order in decending order
    }
```

When I try to decrement the creditCount of a user, I get an error saying the integer value is too small. I have confirmed that the user has 10 credits and they only need to have 1 credit for the code to work. The code I am using is as follows:

```
    try:
        user = User.objects(username=request.args["username"]).get()
        print(user.creditCount)
    except DoesNotExist:
        return "That user does not exist"

    if user.creditCount == 0:
        return "You do not have enough credits to search for a doggo."
    print("credits: " + str(user.creditCount)) #This is where I'm confirming the user has enough credits through the terminal

if os.path.isfile(filePath):
        user.update(dec__creditCount=1)
        return send_file(filePath)
```

I'm not entirely sure what the issue could be since I am validating that the user has more than one credit and also printing their credits to the terminal and they are over one. I am also able to increment the credit count with inc__creditCount=1.

Thanks!
Brad

Answer (score 0):

There is an open ticket about this bug, see
https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/2339